# images based links are getting overlapped when changing screen size(even if rezize the browser window)

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

The link to the jsfiddle is below, pls add images as i m testing locally,i want a web site that appers to be like an app on mobile. 
I have used html,css, and jquerymobile.

my test site : http://kumarindia.byethost24.com/dj.html

and jsfiddle is
http://jsfiddle.net/noo62eclipse/cFKss/1/

```
                <div id="home" data-role="page">
                    <div data-role="header">
                       <h6> welcome to Digital Justice</h6>
                    <div data-role="navbar">
                         <ul>
                        <li><a href="a.html" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="b.html">Two</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    </div>



                    <div id="content" data-role="content">



                          <a href="#court" data-transition="turn" class="court"><img src="court.jpg"alt="Smi" height="100px" width="100px"></a> 
                          <a href="#db" data-transition="turn" class="database"><img src="database.jpg"alt="Smi" height="100" width="100"></a>
                           <a href="#db" data-transition="turn" class="abtus"><img src="abtus.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="100"></a> 

                            </div>  


                    </div>


                <div id="court" data-role="page">
                    <div data-role="header">
                            <h2> your now online in court</h2>  
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="navbar">
                         <ul>
                        <li><a href="a.html" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="b.html">Two</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                            <img src="abtus.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
                            <a href="#" class="akk" data-rel="back" ></a>

                    </div>


                    <div id="db" data-role="page">
                            <h2>please enter your credentials</h2>
                            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                            <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">
                              <label for="fname">your login:</label>
                              <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="your id" >
                              <label for="pass">your password:</label>
                              <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="password">

                              <input type="submit" value="Submit Button" data-corners="true" data-inline="true" data-shadow="true">
                            </form>
                            </div>




                            <div class="cen">

                            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-shadow" data-rel="back" >Go Back</a>
                            </div>
                    </div>  
            </body>         
                </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In responsive development you should use most relative position.
Change your .ui-content css and give it this style:
position: relative; height: 32em; padding-left: 30%; padding-right: 30%;

So now the elements that belong to your div will be at the center with the rest space(40%)

give .court these styles: 
position: relative; top: 0; display: inline-block; float: right; text-align: left; 
width: 50%;

.database and abtus
position: relative; top: 0; display: inline-block; float: left; text-align: left; 
width: 50%;

And add a div in after abtus which will has the same style as .court

AND... you have two class with name court, at one of them you use background url, you have to delete this...

Comment: Ive made a few changes wait ill add only revelent codes

Comment: .court {


position: fixed;
     top: 20%;
    left: 10%;
       

}



.database {


position: fixed;
     top: 20%;
    
    left: 40%;
  
}

.abtus {


position: fixed;
     top: 50%;
    
    left: 40%;

Comment: <div id="content" data-role="content">
                 
                                                           
                        <a href="#court" data-role="button" data-transition="turn" class="court"><img src="court.jpg"alt="Smi" height="100px" width="100px"></a> 
                        <a href="#db" data-role="button" data-transition="turn" class="database"><img src="database.jpg"alt="Smi" height="100px" width="100px"></a>
 <a href="#db" data-role="button" data-transition="turn" class="abtus"><img src="abtus.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="100px" width="100px"></a>  </div>

Comment: making the corrsponding changes leads to a bigger problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714765/anchor-tags-not-linking-to-pages-in-jquery-mobile