# Pages not as responsive in mobile, page elements truncated

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

my test site's page is: http://kumarindia.byethost24.com/dj2.html

The  page links are not as responsive as they are supposed to be in an app.

If u visit the site in an android mobile, the image links get truncated, though it works fine on a laptop.

Any suggestions are welcome, I am using a single page jquery mobile template.  If required ill upload the file sizes if js and CSS used.

Comment: What do you mean? They seem to work when I visit the site with my laptop.

Comment: Yup i rectified and updated it last night. The problem was an unclosed page div.

Comment: Please delete your question if it has become useless. And on the side note, your page transitions are not the best from a user's point of view.

Comment: I've changed the question, better i delete it and start afresh? What do you suggest for page transitions? The site will hold more videos and i will bw linkin it to mysql too

Comment: As u can see i am a toltal newbie in mobile app and related frameworks